# Prove that a product set is dense.

Tags: general-topology

Given $z = (z_i)_{i \in I}$ a fixed point of $\displaystyle\prod_{I}X_i$, where each $X_i$ is non-empty and connected.

For any finite subset $K \subset I$, we define $X_K = \{ (x_i) ∈ \displaystyle\prod_{I}X_i \ | \ x_i = z_i \text{, if } i \in I \setminus K \}$

Finally, we define $A = \{X_K \ | \ K \text{ finite subset of } I\} $

How can one prove that $\bigcup A$ is dense in $\displaystyle\prod_{I}X_i$ ?

---

One needs to show that for any point of $\displaystyle\prod_{I}X_i$ any open set containing it will intersect $\bigcup A$.

I just don't see why it is the case.

Comment: Is it that $\displaystyle\prod_{I}X_i = \bigcup A$ ?

Comment: No, that is in general not the case. Note that you need only prove that every **basic** open set in the product contains a point of $\bigcup A$, and the basic open sets in the product topology are defined in a way that has much in common with the definition of the sets $X_K$.

Comment: Oh. Does it have to do with the canonical subbasis of the product topology?

Comment: Yes; more specifically, with the canonical base formed by taking finite intersections of members of the canonical subbase.

Comment: Right. Thanks! I missed that.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a (non-empty) *basic* open product set $B$ in $\displaystyle \prod_{i \in I} X_i$ it is of the form

$$B=\prod_{i \in I} U_i$$

where there is a finite set $F \subseteq I$ such that $U_i = X_i$ for all $i \in I\setminus F$ and all $U_i$ are (non-empty) open in $X_i$. (These are the finite intersections of sets of the form $p_i^{-1}[U_i]$ which form the standard subbase for the product topology).

Then it's clear that $X_F \cap B \neq \emptyset$ : pick $a_i \in U_i$ for $i \in F$ and define $a_i = z_i$ for all $i \notin F$. Then $(a_i)_i \in X_F \cap B$ and so $B \cap A \neq \emptyset$ as $A \supseteq X_F$ for this $F$ too.

And as all *basic* open sets intersect $A$, *all* open sets do too (they are unions of basic open sets after all). So $A$ is dense.